# Shortening exponential additions - exp( ... ) + exp( ... ) +

Tags: math, exponential

I have a statistical formula in my code

```
x = exp( a1 ) + exp( a2 ) + exp( a2 ) + .... exp( an )
```

But all those exp(...) are slightly expensive especially if there are a lot

Is there a 'shorter' way of evaluating the expression just once?

```
x = exp( a1 ... an )
```

Comment: Unless the exponents are the same or factored to match and simplified. I don't think there's a way to shortcut adding exponential functions.

Comment: In general no, sorry

Comment: Math can't help, but multiple processors can.  Perhaps parallelizing the calculation, a la map/reduce, would make it faster as long as the overhead wasn't too high.  The more values you have, the more attractive the possibility.

Comment: There are some numerical approximations that can help, depending on the size of the `a_i`.  How exact of an answer do you need?

Comment: if the number of different exponents is limited, just cache it or use a lookup table

Answer (score 0):

no it's not possible . Depending on the language you use, it may be worthwhile to try different math-libraries (implemented in C/Fortran) or, depending on the number of terms to sum up, using multiple threads (as the exponentials can be calculated independently of each other)